# How to Enable My Laptop to Receive HTTP Requests from the Internet

Tags: ubuntu, security, firewall, http, hosting

Sorry for the noob question since I am clueless about some networking concepts.

I am running a uvicorn server on my laptop (Linux Mint Ulyana) that I can access via localhost from my browser. I mark the host as 0.0.0.0 which I believe is necessary to expose the service to the internet, but still my colleague (who is in a different timezone) cannot send a request when I give him my IP address.

When I run the same service from an azure VM with Ubuntu 18.04, then it is automatically exposed to the internet.

My internet connection is from a regular home broadband provider who assigns me a dynamic ip address from each session. I am giving the ip address shown on [IP Address Checker](https://api.ipify.org/) to my colleague. Also, I am allowing inbound connection on my firewall.

EDIT: Some additional information based on the comments

- I am connecting to the internet via a TP Link Archer WiFi router
- The uvicorn server (built with fastapi) is running at port 8000 with http

[image]

Comment: Are you connected directly to your ISP, or do you have a router? If you have a router, you need to set up port forwarding. Also note that some ISPs block inbound connections unless you pay for a static IP address.

Comment: In addition to this, you probably have port 80 blocked (assuming that you *REALLY* mean http and not https) on the end of your machine.  Step one, unblock port 80 using iptables.  Step two, ensure this machine can be accessed from *another machine* WITHIN your network (using the local 192.186** or 10.10.** address).  Step three, use port forwarding as @MosheKatz is directing you to do.  This will allow your real public IP to be forwarded from port 80 to your private 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x address.

Comment: Firewalls on the computer itself may be another problem. Also, regarding ISPs potentially blocking a connection, one thing to check for is [CGNAT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). In short, check your router WAN against your [public IP address](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip). If they are different, then CGNAT may be an issue.

Comment: EXACTLY @Anaksunaman !! That was what I was *trying* to say as one of the two parts that need to work!  I jumped right to iptables when this isn't a good description :)

Comment: Glad to help "demystify" your otherwise  excellent comment a little. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In general there are several safeguards in place to prevent outside access into a network, which can very easily abused by attackers. In your situation, your local router may deny it, and your ISP may deny it as well. The fact that is commercial is not a guarantee that you can host anything.